# factor scores from CFA in lavaan

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I have the covariance matrix and an already fitted lavaan object (and/or model) using the cov matrix. But, I do not have the raw data. Is there a way I can calculate the factor scores?

Comment: What would the factor scores relate to if you don't have the raw data?

Comment: You can, but as Jeremy Miles points out there won't be any correspondence to "real" data. You could for instance simulate raw data using the covariance matrix and then feed it to your lavaan model (may also need the mean vector depending on the model). I can imagine scenarios where this might be helpful for plotting/interpretation, but not sure what your specific use case is.